# If disconnection can prompt to web service?

Tags: client-server

If a client comes online, then the remote computer calls a method that makes that user online by setting the status to online in the database, on the web. Similar is for when client closes his application then the status becomes offline in the database.

If the client becomes offline during the program then the the status in the database will remain online.

How can this problem be solved?

Comment: Write a `void Ping()` method in your webservice and update the db with last ping time. If last ping time is older than, say 5m, you can treat the client as offline

Comment: thanks i got that and found a way.